# Patch becoming empty when running with packer build. How to fix this

Tags: linux, bash, patch, packer

I have automated a image build process in a cloud environment using packer tool.

It installs lot of tools and applies lot of patches using linux path tool.

Everything is working as expected when doing manually. But with packer automation I'm facing one issue with apllying patch.

There is a config file at `/etc/myprogram/myconfig.cfg`.

I'm running patch like this.

`pushd /etc/myprogram
patch -p 0 < myconfig.cfg.patch`

Patch is applying successfully when running manually. But with packer that target file is becoming empty.

But in stdout of packer build i can see output like 2 hunks applied.

What cloud be the issue ? Please some suggestions to debug this.

`packer build base.json`

base.json

```
{
    "builders": [
        {
            "flavor": "general1-8",
            "image_name": "Havell Build {{ timestamp }}",
            "source_image": "d944e490-f615-49a5-97f7-b80a8b0398d4",
            "ssh_keypair_name": "packer-manual",
            "ssh_private_key_file": "packer-manual.key",
            "ssh_username": "root",
            "type": "openstack"
        }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
        {   "type": "shell",
            "inline": "mkdir -p /tmp/patches/"
        },
        {
            "type": "file",
            "source": "patches/",
            "destination": "/tmp/patches/"
        },
        {
            "script": "apply_patches.sh",
            "type": "shell"
        }
    ]
}
```

apply_patches.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

echo "*********************before************************"
echo "***************************************************"
cat /etc/myprogram/myconfig.cfg
echo "***************************************************"
echo "***************************************************"
pushd /etc/myprogram
patch -p 0 < myconfig.cfg.patch

echo "***********************after***********************"
echo "***************************************************"
cat /etc/myprogram/myconfig.cfg
echo "***************************************************"
echo "***************************************************"

exit 0
```

Comment: Could you update your line about how you run patch. That doesn't work and I expected that isn't what you are running.

Comment: @RickardvonEssen, I have updated patch line

Comment: Is your patch located at `/etc/myprogram/myconfig.cfg.patch`? Have you verified that?

Comment: yes. Its there ..

Comment: In what situations patch tool makes a target file as empty?

Comment: Provide your full packer template and scripts. There is probably just an simple bug in your scripts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146162/discussion-between-rmkrjy-and-rickard-von-essen).

Comment: i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to read:

```
pushd /etc/myprogram
patch -p 0 < /tmp/patches/myconfig.cfg.patch
```